# Can a wireshark capture filter scan for two different patterns?

Tags: wireshark

I need a capture filter that looks for a 4-byte machine ID that can occur in several places in the UDP payload.  Specifically,

```
udp[18:4]==0x76123AA6 or udp[20:4]==0x76123AA6 or udp[25:4]==0x76123AA6
```

Experimenting with pieces of this filter does locate some desired packets, but if I use the above filter, some packets are not passed through the filter as expected.

Do the no-loop rules of the BPF interpreter prevent this kind of multiple-match filtering?

Comment: If that's not matching, there's something else not right.  That is precisely how you match one or more conditions.

Comment: If you're capturing with `tcpdump` or `dumpcap`, you can use the `-d` option to dump the BPF generated code which might help you verify if the capture filter that you're applying is correct or not.  Wireshark can also show you the BPF generated code via *"Capture -> Options -> Capture filter: udp[18:4]==0x76123AA6 or udp[20:4]==0x76123AA6 or udp[25:4]==0x76123AA6 -> Compile BPFs"*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason I seemed to be missing some packets: the search patterns must be listed in the capture filter in sequential order.

For example, this filter will potentially miss some packets:

```
udp[18:4]==0x12345678 or udp[24:4]==0x12345678 or udp[20:4]==0x12345678
```

because the scope of the last pattern (20:4) is later in the data than an earlier pattern (24:4).

In order to work as expected the filter must be written like this:

```
udp[18:4]==0x12345678 or udp[20:4]==0x12345678 or udp[24:4]==0x12345678
```

I unknowningly wrote out the filter correctly in the original question; my code had the filter in the incorrect format.